# School wants me to install a root certificate to connect to their network on my personal laptop

Tags: spyware, root

What would this do? I'm a bit of a beginner to root certificates so stay with me here, I Don't want it to be able to see what I'm doing at home.

Comment: This would allow them to replace the website encryption with their own (to read your network traffic). They would need to be between your computer and the Internet, so they won't be able to do it while you're at home unless they install some other software (proxy etc.).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would a school need to install certificates on student laptops?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201106/), [My college is forcing me to install their SSL certificate. How to protect my privacy?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/104576/), [How does having a custom root certificate installed from school or work cause one to be monitored?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/244571/), ....